# How do you set up IPv6 alongside an IPv4-based NAT configuration?

Tags: networking, ipv6, iptables, nat

I'm looking to route all my traffic from my IPv4 NAT to an IPv6 address I have. I googled around on the Internet for a good tutorial on this, and could not find one. Right now I have my network setup with IPv4 NAT using `iptables` in Linux.

Can someone please point me to the right direction on this? Maybe a URL that you may know of?

Also is it possible to use `ip6tables` and `iptables` together ?

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use `ip6tables` and `iptables` together. Think of IPv4 and IPv6 as completely separate [Layer 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Layer) stacks.

Since [NAT is currently not supported or recommended for use with IPv6, and there is no standard for it](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5902), you will probably need to get a routed `/64` for your network rather than use a single IP address. (At least, that's the [IETF recommendation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6177).) If you were relying on NAT to protect your network in some way, (prevent connections from the outside to your internal hosts) you'll have to [protect it some other way](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4864).

I'm not sure what you use for a router, but mine is based on DD-WRT, which has a [good tutorial for getting IPv6 up and running](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/IPv6). Since you are using a Linux-based router, the basics might apply in your case as well.

Comment: "IPv6-to-IPv6 Network Prefix Translation (NPTv6) is a specification for IPv6 to achieve address-independence at the network edge, similar to network address translation (NAT) in Internet Protocol version 4 (IPv4)." https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6296

Comment: Yes, thank you @TCB13; at the time I wrote this answer, that RFC had not yet been published.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where you're getting your IPv6 connectivity from, but if your ISP doesn't support it natively, I can recommend [Sixxs](http://www.sixxs.net).

Their guide for deploying the setup you want is at http://www.sixxs.net/wiki/Installing_a_Subnet. I use it at home over my existing IPv4 NAT connection, with a Linux machine as my router (using ip6tables) and it works perfectly.